# SIMD - загрузка в регистры из выравненной и не выравненной памяти

Tags: c++, c, simd

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть две SIMD-"функции" загружающие данные из памяти в регистры:

1)_mm_load_si128 (__m128i const* mem_addr)
2)_mm_loadu_si128 (__m128i const* mem_addr)

> __m128i _mm_load_si128 (__m128i const* mem_addr):

> Загружает 128-битные целочисленные данные из памяти в dst . mem_addr должен быть выровнен
> по 16-байтовой границе, иначе может быть сгенерировано исключение
> общей защиты.

.

> __m128i _mm_loadu_si128 (__m128i const* mem_addr):
>
> Загружает 128-битные целочисленные данные из памяти в dst . mem_addr
> не нужно выравнивать по какой-либо конкретной границе.

Я ни как не могу понять, как в данном случае влияет выравнивание источника памяти по 16-байтовой границе.

Ну то есть обе "функции" принимается на вход указатель на па память, обе функции считывают от этого указателя ровно 16 байт к себе в регистры. Что в данном  контексте означает выравнивание памяти по 16 байтовой границе ?

Comment: Это означает, что значение адреса, хранящее в переданном указателе, в первом случае должно быть кратно 16, иначе будет бо-бо, а во втором - может быть любым.

Comment: @user7860670, Спасибо!

Comment: @user7860670, позвольте уточняющий вопрос: Но ведь я не могу повлиять на на то с какого адреса начинается буфер памяти из которого нужно загрузить данные в регистры. Получается прежде, чем применять ту или иную инструкцию - нужно для начала провести простой анализ на кратность 16 байт ?

Comment: Наоборот, при использовании функции, требующей выравнивания, обеспечение надлежащего выравнивания буфера является вашей обязанностью.

Comment: @user7860670, но, как можно выровнять уже запалённый буфер, особенно, если этот буфер выдала к примеру, какая то другая функция, то есть, если я даже этот буфер не заполнял. Это ведь придется создавать новый буфер кратного 16 байтам размера и перекопировать туда данные из первоначального буфера, но если так, то это же трата времени.

Comment: Ну так вот если хотите использовать быстрые функции, требующие выравнивания памяти, то вам надо делать такое приложение, которое бы с самого начала работы с этими данными выравнивало их надлежащим образом. А если буфер выдает какая-то другая функция и от этого никак не уйти, то тогда да, придется выкручиваться - либо копировать данные в новый буфер, либо делать альтернативную версию алгоритма, которая бы работала на невыравненных данных.

Comment: Часто такая версия может быть сделана гибридно - например первые и последние x байт буфера обрабатываются без использования SIMD инструкций, а кусок буфера между ними, который окажется с  выравниванием - с использованием SIMD инструкций.

Comment: Если этот буфер вы создаёте сами, то смотрите в сторону `_aligned_malloc` и `alignas`.

Comment: @user7860670 есть второй вариант работы с невыравненной памятью: использовать маски. _mm_maskmoveu_si128() и т.п...